How to set up multiple languages for an App
I´m new on this and before I start practicing and developing any App I have a question about the languages. When I´m in a country and I download and App in the Google App Store, the App download in the language of that country.
My question is: If I want my App to be in multiple countries, do I need to develop the App in all those languages and then load the App in each language to the corresponding country Google App Store? For example: should I write my app in: English, French and Spanish and load the English version to (US, Australia, England, etc) French Version to (France) and Spanish Version to (Spain, Argentina, Mexico, etc)?
And if not, how the langage App thing works?
Thank you very much

You write one app, and provide a file of all the strings in your app (called the string resource file) in each language you wish to support.  If you want to support different translations for different versions of a language (such as french canadian and french france) you can do that as well using the same technique.  So long as you never hardcode strings and always use the string resource system, adding a new language to your app is as simple as getting that one file translated.
